# Cannot pass enum to function PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, enums

I have cut the code down to just show what is currently breaking, assume I've grabbed the appropriate objects properly:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common')
#$team is of type TeamFoundationTeam Class
$allMembers =  $team.GetMembers($tfs, ([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.MembershipQuery]::Direct))
```

Then I get the following message:

> Cannot convert argument "queryMembership", with value: "Direct", for
>   "GetMembers" to type 
>   "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.MembershipQuery": "Cannot
>   convert value "Direct" to type 
>   "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.MembershipQuery"

So I've tried casting the enum, wrapping the enum in parenthesis, not wrapping the enum in parenthesis, adding the reference by explicit version using add-type, tried adding the reference with the above lazy method by load partial, tried deleting my local TFS cache. I'm all out of ideas how to get this to work. The weird thing is that this was working when I last worked on it a couple days ago. Is there something weird about Enums in powershell I'm missing? How do I get this to work?

I'm using powershell v3.0.

[TeamFoundationTeam.GetMembers()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.teamfoundationteam.getmembers(v=vs.120).aspx)

[MembershipQuery Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.membershipquery(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: How about just `'Direct'`?

Comment: Worked... thanks. Sorry but powershell has too many stupid gotcha's. Edit: throw this as the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Can you show output of `$team.GetType().Assembly.FullName` and `[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.MembershipQuery].Assembly.FullName`?

Comment: Did you mean you have figured out the issue by using `$allMembers =  $team.GetMembers($tfs, Direct)` in your ps script?

Comment: Yes, oddly enough it fixed it (in quotes though as suggested). I think there's implicit type conversion going on. What would you do if you had two enums with the same property name but two different namespaces?